# ASP.NET MVC 3.0 Url Routing Issue

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2, razor

Hi I have registered route as below :-

```
 routes.MapLocalizedRoute("Category",
                        "{SeName}-c{categoryId}",
                        new { controller = "Catalog", action = "Category", SeName =       UrlParameter.Optional },
                        new { categoryId = @"\d+", SeName = @"([-\w+]+(/[-\w+]+)*)+" },
                        new[] { "Nop.Web.Controllers" });

 routes.MapLocalizedRoute("CategoryWithManufacture",
                   "{SeName}-d{categoryId}/{ManufactureName}/{Color}",
                   new { controller = "Catalog", action = "Category", SeName = UrlParameter.Optional, Color = UrlParameter.Optional },
                   new { categoryId = @"\d+", SeName = @"([-\w+]+(/[-\w+]+)*)+", ManufactureName = @"([-\w+]+(/[-\w+]+)*)+", Color = @"([-\w+]+(/[-\w+]+)*)+" },
                   new[] { "Nop.Web.Controllers" });
```

We generate these like below :-

```
 href="@Url.RouteUrl("CategoryWithManufacture", new { categoryId = currentCategoryId, SeName = seName, ManufactureName = manufacturerFilterItem.Name, Color = color })"


 href="@Url.RouteUrl("Category", new { categoryId = currentCategoryId, SeName = seName})"
```

There is a way to assign value directly to second parameter "Color" without assign value to "ManufactureName". means :- (Using CategoryWithManufacture Route)

```
/gloves-d18/red  (second parameter)
/gloves-d18/hp/red (first and second both)
```

I have tried these by making manufactureName & color both optional but when we assign value to first parameter not second it , it work . But we assign value to second parameter not first ,then it is not work .

Please suggest me usable link or sample code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the last parameter can be optional in a route definition. Given the following url `/gloves-d18/red` the route engine cannot possible know that `red` refers here to `{Color}` and not `{ManufactureName}`. The only to make this work is to write some constraint for those 2 parts. Right now they both have the exactly same regular expression constraint.

Comment: please suggest me any modification in my route.